# Speeding up a MySQL stored routine

Tags: mysql, performance

I was wondering if it was possible to speed up this MySQL query.  Currently, I am calling it 20,000+ times, and it takes a while to run (a while being about 10 to 20 minutes).

Here is the basic table layout:

```
db1:
INT(11) id
VARCHAR(45) col1
VARCHAR(100) col2
VARCHAR(100) col3

db2:
VARCHAR(45) id

db3:
VARCHAR(45) fk_db2
INT(11) fk_db1
```

Here is the stored routine:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc`(IN fk VARCHAR(45),
                                            IN a VARCHAR(45),
                                            IN b VARCHAR(100),
                                            IN c VARCHAR(65))
BEGIN
    SET @id=0;
    SELECT id INTO @id FROM db1 WHERE db1.col1=a
                                AND db1.col2=b
                                AND db1.col3=c;
    IF @id=0 THEN
        INSERT INTO db1 (col1, col2, col3)
            VALUES (a, b, c);
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @id;
    END IF;

    -- Association table for db2 and db1.
    INSERT IGNORE INTO db3 (fk_db1, fk_db2) 
        VALUES(@id, fk);
END
```

The main point of this routine, is I want to get the ID of a specific record, or create one if it doesn't exist.  Then I want to associate the fk passed in and the ID that I just found out.  I'm sure there is a MySQL one-liner for this, but I have been unable to figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

**Thank you!**

By the way, the names of columns are much better in the actual database, but I can't share the names with you all.

Comment: How are you calling it? In 20,000+ different transactions or one big transaction?

Comment: I was calling it in many small transactions, but I thought it would be faster if I did one big transaction, I am testing that now, but still appears slow.

Comment: I would have thought that it should be somewhat faster as each Commit will require a write to disc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, unless I'm missing something, that doesn't look all that slow. Can you define "a while" in "takes a while"?

Do you have an index on col1/col2/col3?

How exactly are you calling the procedure in your application? You are reusing the database connections, right?

Can you bundle multiple calls into a single transaction if you're not already?

Comment: A while is about 10 - 20 minutes (long enough for me to write the question and do a lot of searching the internet to figure out an answer).

I do not have an index on col1, col2, or col3.

In my application, I have one database connection and I am executing the statements in a batch.

Comment: @KLee1: Well, there's your problem. You're doing a SELECT on a table without indexes on the appropriate columns. That will make things incredibly slow. Add indexes.

Comment: You should time that first select, and  view the query plan for it, likely you could benefit from adding indexes to the db1 table.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions everyone (+1s around) I have to admit that I'm not very familiar with indexes, as I learned MySQL about 7 days ago.  I'll read up on them and try them when I get to work tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks guys! Indexes helped the speed a lot.  Now only takes about a minute.